# Удаление повтора символа с помощью регулярного выражения в js

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Есть код для проверки поля ввода на ввод числа (или точки в качестве разделителя дробной части):

```
$('#input_price').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
  if (this.value.match(/[,]/g)) {                                       
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, '.');
  }
  if (this.value.match(/[^0-9.]/g)) {     
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  }
});
```

В этом коде не существует ограничения на количество введенных точек. Возможно ли его как-то изменить, чтобы после ввода очередной точки предыдущая точка в поле ввода удалялась?

Например, если после ввода `123.50` ввести разделитель еще раз в конце строки, строка приобретет вид `12350.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поиска повторяющего символа в регулярных выражениях существует несколько квантификаторов:

- `a*` соответствует нулю или больше символов `a`
- `a+` соответствует одному или больше символов `a`
- `a?` соответствует нулю или одному символу `a`
- `a{2,4}` соответствует от двух до четырех символов `a`
- `a{3,}` соответствует трем или более символов `a`
- `a{5}` соответствует ровно пяти символам `a`

Как можно было догадаться, в вашем случае нужно добавить в код следующую конструкцию:

```
  // Заменяем все группы, содержащие более одной точки, на одну точку
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\.+/g, '.');
```

**UPD**:

А вот если разделитель идет не подряд и нужно сохранить только последнее вхождение разделителя в строке, то тут одним регулярным выражением не обойтись. Вот пример кода, который оставляет только последнее вхождение разделителя в строке

```
var dotsCount = (value.match(/\./g) || []).length;
if (dotsCount > 1) {
  var dotPos = 0;
  value = value.replace(/\./g, function() {
    if (dotPos === (dotsCount - 1)) {
      // Для последней точки в строке, замену производить не нужно
      return '.';
    }
    dotPos++;

    // Удаляем все точки в строке, кроме последней
    return '';
  });
}
```

А вот и JSFiddle для вашего, конкретного случая: http://jsfiddle.net/xzgowj95/

**UPD2:**

Кстати, использование

```
this.value.match(...)
```

в вашем случае избыточно, поскольку конструкция

```
this.value.replace(...)
```

вернет исходную строку, если не сможет найти подстроки для замены.

Comment: Код не работает. Повторы разделителя не удаляются, курсор не становится в середину строки. Возможно, я что-то делаю неправильно. Как в целом должен выглядеть код?

Comment: Да, действительно, в моем коде была опечатка (которая, кстати, _очевидна при прочтении сопровождающего текста_). Исправил. А вот и ссылка на JSFiddle с рабочим кодом: http://jsfiddle.net/rwvmg5ax/

Comment: К сожалению, повтор разделителя в примере не удаляется, если после первого разделителя вводились числа, например 123.456.789

Comment: Переформулируйте оригинальный вопрос, отразив этот пример и ожидаемые результаты выполнения кода.

Comment: Отличный код, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли его как-то изменить, чтобы после ввода очередной точки предыдущая точка в поле ввода удалялась?

Нет, потому что ты не знаешь, в какой позиции стоит курсор, а следовательно, какую именно точку надо удалять.

И вообще, присваивать значение на каждое нажатие - это жуть. Потому что курсор будет скакать либо в последнюю, либо в первую позицию.